# BLE in STM32WB does not work on a custom PCB board. How to check where the problem is?

Tags: stm32, bluetooth-low-energy, troubleshooting

STM32 - STM32WB55CGU6
Antenna - 2450AT18B100E
Filter - MLPF-WB-01E3

Please help me fix the problem with my custom PCB board and BLE. The antenna on the board won’t work (I don't see my device via Bluetooth) in any way and I don’t know where to look.

Can anyone implement Bluetooth via filter MLPF-WB-01E3 and antenna 2450AT18B100E on STM32WB? I suspect that there is a problem with the board, since I run similar code on Nucleo and I can see the device through my phone, but I can't see the device through my phone.

Does anyone know how to check where the error is, and to check if I designed the board correctly?

[image]

Comment: What makes you certain that it's the antenna at fault and not an oscillator problem or some other layout issue?

Comment: I am not sure that antenna

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but, to help people searching and finding this. Don't forget to program the correct BLE stack onto your processor, and in the correct location. Start with that.